# Does a CollectionView's childView have to be an ItemView?

Tags: backbone.js, view, marionette, childviews

I am trying to get a final layout like...

- Left Column (collectionView)

  - PanelLayout(LayoutView)

    - BannerView (ItemView)
    - ContentView (LayoutView)

      - Section1 (CompositeView)

        - gridRow (ItemView)
  - PanelLayout(LayoutView)

    - BannerView (ItemView)
    - ContentView (LayoutView)

      - Section1 (CompositeView)

        - gridRow (ItemView)

but my Left Column (collectionView) does not want to show the panelLayout(LayoutView). Is it possible to have a childView: that is a LayoutView (like the example below) and not a ItemView (http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.2/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-childview)

```
class panelLayoutView extends Marionette.LayoutView
template: Templates['panel']

regions:{

    bannerRegion: "#banner-region"
    contentRegion: "#content-region"
}



class leftColumnCollectionView extends Marionette.CollectionView
    className: "leftColumn column"
    childView: panelLayoutView
    childViewContainer: "leftColumn"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is absolutely nothing wrong with using a `LayoutView` or any other Marionette view type as the `childView` for a `CollectionView`.

Comment: hmmm. I'm unsure why this did not work for me then. I've taken a different approach to rendering my views now so I can't recreate what was happening at this time.

If anyone is curious how I ended up rendering multiple views under a collectionView : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460936/how-to-render-a-collection-of-different-marionette-views